# VirtualBox keeps giving error when I try to start a new machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit, uninstall

So I am running Windows 7 (the 64-bit version) with a 64-bit processor (I checked) right now and have downloaded and installed VirtualBox. I want to run Kali Linux on it so I created my first virtual machine. Now at first it was only giving the 32-bit options for the operating system I want to run, but after some Googling, I found I needed to go into the BIOS at startup and enable "Virtualization Technology." Doing this worked, and it then began giving 64-bit options.

So I chose Linux for the operating system and Debian 64-bit as the specific since Kali is built on Debian. I created the VM but then got the error message. Some further Googling revealed it might be conflicting anti-virus or Trusteer Rapport, which I found is installed on the system. Now I used Norton 360, but I found a couple of other ant-virus programs, so I uninstalled those but no luck. I don't want to have to uninstall Norton as it has blocked viruses before.

I tried to uninstall Rapport, but the computer won't do it. Windows just says it is preparing to uninstall....then configuring Rapport, and that's that. Some Googling and I found you may need administrator privileges to uninstall it, but my account is the administrator, so I should be able to uninstall it. I am wondering if maybe I **should** uninstall it...? (as it is supposed to aid security with online banking).

Anyhow, to summarize, I have a 64-bit operating system and a 64-bit processor, I have enabled Virtualization Technology in the BIOS, I have Norton 360 active, and I have tried to uninstall Rapport but it won't uninstall and I don't know if that's the problem anyhow nor if I should uninstall it.

Here is the text of the specific error:

***Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali.
The virtual machine 'Kali' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Prentice\VirtualBox VMs\Kali\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}***

Thanks

Comment: I have seen a number of Virtual Box and Kali errors. Try making a Kali guest in a trial version of VMware Workstation. I have Kali running well in VMware.

Comment: What error is shown in the mentioned `VBoxHardening.log`? Please edit your question and add the relevant lines from this log file.

Comment: I tried the trial version of VMWare and that works just fine, so John thanks for the suggestion. Robert, what do error do you mean? I posted the error I saw above, but not sure what other errors there are...?